# how to change keyboard language programmatically

Tags: android

I have made android app. my client ask me that change default language at soft keyboard case by case. one case, keyboard should be English keyboard, another, Korean keyboard.

how can i do?

Comment: hi , did you successfully changed the keyboard languages pro-grammatically ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer Latin IMe @grep code site . In that lookfor keyboardswitcher.class