# Change default keyboard language in mobile app

Tags: html, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a html5 based hybrid application and it is for a german client. Everything is completed and stumbled into one problem.

The web app is in german, but while accessing the application, the keyboard is english one and i need to change it to german.

Specifying

```
<html lang="de">
```

dint work really.

Ive found some questions related to android/iOs application and found in iOS you cannot do this. But in android, someone was able to solve this.

[how to change keyboard language programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488630/how-to-change-keyboard-language-programmatically)

Is there a way in html5 apps?

I am using backbone.js + phonegap

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really that possible. You can change the users locale.

Number of solutions present on stackoverflow already:

[Here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701882/android-change-language-programmatically), or [Here another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android).

However, this will only change the locale. The problem you will encounter is that the keyboard is itself an application. Therefore, you cannot change it directly from your application, nor can you guarantee that your user will have the "German" charset or addon or whatever, for they keyboard app that they employ.

Your only real and reliable solution if you wish to accomplish what you need would be to create your own keyboard input. Otherwise, it will be in the user's hands to change their keyboard to German.

That means you have to change input language yourself.

Comment: Yes, i saw the above solutions, but all that being native ones specific to android...:(

Comment: yah, but i think do not have any other solution.